# Webcam on MacBook Pro turned on randomly, and wouldn't turn off. What spyware/malware to look for?

Tags: malware, virus, macos, spyware

I have a 2015 MacBook Pro, and tonight when I opened my laptop, FaceTime was open and my webcam light was on. I never open FaceTime on my laptop, and I know for sure that the last time I closed my laptop it wasn't running.

After I exited FaceTime the light was still on, so I checked my sharing settings and no screen sharing or anything like that is checked. Since the light was still on, I opened activity manager and noticed `AppleCameraAssistant` running with root access. I ended the task and the light went off.

I know it's probably nothing, but I want to make 100% sure that I don't have any spyware or malware installed. I downloaded Sophos and Malwarebytes and ran both, but it only caught a couple things that I don't believe are related. The one thing that comes to mind is that this past week I have installed python along with a few drivers that I had to install locally, but everything I installed was from the verified location, I believe.

I guess my question is, what is the best way to thoroughly check my Mac to make sure there is nothing on it, including root access, etc? I included a link to a screen cap of my downloads for the past 7 days if anyone wants to take a look, and see if anything sticks out to them. If anyone actually wants to take a look at my activity monitor running processes, I can post a link for that also.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I'd double check the 'setup.exe' file from the screenshot, might be the culprit.

Comment: thanks for the response, I just checked it out and it was just a web scraper program called helium that I downloaded and didn't realize it was for windows so I never installed it. would you recommend using a rootkit detector software or anything to that extreme?

Comment: Remember what FBI director James Comey says he does:  He puts a band-aid over the camera, because you never know when it might be on.

Comment: Rootkit detectors are not the solution. The solution is to wipe the harddrive.